# How to create/destroy dynamic objects after the same event in QML?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a GridLayout `dynamicLayout` which has dynamically created/destroyed elements. Create/destroy happens when I click a Button `myButton`, for which I also provided the code below.

```
GridLayout {
    id: dynamicLayout
    anchors.fill: parent

    Component {
        id: imageComponent
        Image {
            visible: true
            function deleteImage() {
                console.log("destroying image")
                destroy()
            }
        }
    }
}

    Button {
    id: myButton
    visible: true
    x: 200
    y: 200

    onClicked: {
        createImageObjects();
    }
}


function createImageObjects() {
    if (imageComponent.status == Component.Ready)
        finishCreation();
    else
        imageComponent.statusChanged.connect(finishCreation);
}

function finishCreation() {
    if (imageComponent.status == Component.Ready) {
        for (var i= 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var object = imageComponent.createObject(dynamicLayout, {"width": 100, "height": 100, "source": FILE_PATH});
            if (object == null) {
                // Error Handling
                console.log("Error creating object");
            } else {
               myButton.clicked.connect(object.deleteImage)
            }
        }
    } else if (imageComponent.status == Component.Error) {
        // Error Handling
        console.log("Error loading component:", imageComponent.errorString());
    }
}
```

So what I intend to do is to add 3 new images to the layout when the button is clicked and while deleting the older 3 images. However, the newer 3 images are created first and after that all of the 6 images are destroyed  at once. (I get 6 'destroying images' message with the same click event)

How can I postpone the connecting to the next click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to use the two step object creation method - it is only necessary when you are loading components from remote sources, which is done asynchronously. You don't really need that for loading components from local storage, even less so when your `Component` is in-line in the source.

Second, due to the way multiple signal connections stack, when you press your button, you execute the first connection which is the creation function, which adds more connections, so they are executed after the first connection, which leads to the immediate deletion of the objects that were just created. There isn't a nice way to say "don't process those connections until next time". You could use a timer to delay the connections, but aside from clumsy, that also opens room for bugs.

Your design is plain out bad. Instead you should go for something simple and functional. For example, have a `property var images : []` - a JS array in which you store references to the existing images. So each time you press the button - delete the existing images if any, then create the new ones and push them into the array. You will also save on connections and event handling this way.

Comment: I am actually new to javascript and wanted to save objects in an array but wasn't sure if that was possible. So how do you do it in my case?

Comment: Yes it is possible. However, what is the purpose of your code? You are creating 3 images without a source, showing nothing? It is likely you don't even need to create the objects manually, you could use a model and a repeater.

Comment: I didn't provide the first part but before the first click happens, createImages is called once so I have 3 images replaced on the first click

Comment: Your images have no image source. What is the purpose of creating image elements which show no image?

Comment: You should explain what is it that you actually want to achieve, because likely there is a much better way than the one you are taking. What is the practical goal here?

Comment: I want to have a gridlayout which has child items. The number of items also their properties such as width, height are determined/changed during the runtime. That's why I chose to use dynamic object creation. Let's say I have 10 images to show but 3 fits to screen. So I have to replace the first 3 with the next 3...

Comment: I mean, at first I show the first 3 and when I click next button I replace the first 3 with the next 3